# Parsing more than one integer into a single string

Tags: java, string

How can I parse more than one integer into a single string?

For example:

```
int a,b,c,d;
String parsed;
a=(int)(Math.random*10);
b=(int)(Math.random*10);
c=(int)(Math.random*10);
d=(int)(Math.random*10);
```

I could code:

```
parsed = Integer.toString(a);
parsed = Integer.toString(b);
parsed = Integer.toString(c);
parsed = Integer.toString(d);
```

But I want the variable `parsed` to contain the `String` values of a,b,c, and d, in possibly one line of code.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; `parseInt` takes a `String`, not an `int`.

Comment: my bad.....corrected

Comment: Let's say a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4. do you want the output be the string "1234"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient way to get small random numbers is to use Random.nextInt(n)

```
Random random = new Random();

String fourDigits = String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(10000));
```

Answer (score 2):

Integer.parseInt() is used to parse an integer from a String, no the other way around.

It looks like you want to concatenate the integers to a String.

Here's one way to do it :

```
parsed = "" + a + b + c + d;
```

Of course, instead of concatening 4 random single digit integers, you can create a 4 digit integer and convert it to String :

```
parsed = Integer.toString ((int)(Math.random*10000));
```

Comment: Yes, but at some point this code will generate less than 4 integers